# Angular 5 WebStorm Run Configuration

Tags: angular, webstorm, run-configuration

I'm surprised to see Angular does not yet have an entry in Jet Brain's IDE, WebStorm, which run config do you guys use?

I want to execute: `ng serve`

but Maybe there's a better option?

one like vue's `npm run dev` which opens up a page in your default browser at the served address?

this page didn't hit run configs, https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/angular.html

UPDATE :

for clarification I'm talking about making a one click run button like you can for react and vue apps :

[image]

Comment: Work fine for me on a clean angular-cli project with webstorm terminal with `ng serve`

Comment: I also use `ng serve` from the PhpStorm terminal on a clean angular-cli project and it works

Comment: Are you referring to the debug configurations?

Comment: you guys I meant the green arrow at the top this way the app is one-click-to-run, it runs fine from powershell or the webstorm terminal I just want to upgrade from that and do what I did for my react and vue apps.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please see https://blog.jetbrains.com/webstorm/2017/01/debugging-angular-apps/ for instructions on debugging Angular apps in WebStorm.

- right-click your `package.json`, choose **Show NPM Scripts**
- in **NPM** tool window, click the `start` script to start the app
- create a new **JavaScript debug** configuration (**Run –> Edit configurations… –> Add –> JavaScript Debug**), etter `http://localhost:4200/` into the **URL** field, press **Debug**

Comment: latest webstorm EAP includes clickable run arrows next to each run entry yin the package.json much in the fashion of MAVEN/Gradle

Comment: Answer that is similar to this, but simpler:   
https://stackoverflow.com/a/77742892/8644294

Answer (score 2):

Just open `package.json` and add the script you want. You can add any script in `"script"` section. The add your script from the configurations.